# How to mock a Wicket component

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, wicket, spock

I am trying to unittest a wicket panel with the help of WicketTester and Spock/Mockito.

In this panel, a `ModalWindow` (confirmation dialog) is show in a good case scenario.

I want to validate this dialog will be shown, so I tried to mock the component, inject it into the panel and test if the `show` method is called.
This won't work, as Wicket throws the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.wicket.Component has not been properly detached. 
Something in the hierarchy of X has not called super.onDetach() in the override of onDetach() method
```

It's not suprising a mock can not call the `onDetach` method on it's super class.

I've tried stubbing the `ModalWindow` and using a spy to verify if the `show` method is called, but the implementation of that method has dependencies / external calls that are hard to mock.

Which way should I approach this problem? Or shouldn't I even try to make this kind of test work?

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a custom version of ModalWindow that just overrides #show() method to call super.show() and to raise a flag that the method is called.
Then use this custom version in the test of the panel.